# What type of encryption does Windows 10 virtual WIFI hotspot use?

Tags: encryption, wifi, windows-10, hotspot

Hi I am planning on using the WIFI hotspot feature provided by Windows 10 to connect to 4 robots, however I do not know what type of encryption this windows 10 hotspot uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPA2-AES, [according to Microsoft.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243(v=vs.85).aspx)

> To provide protection for the wireless communications between the computer hosting SoftAP and the devices connecting to the SoftAP, the wireless Hosted Network requires that all devices connected use the WPA2-PSK/AES cipher suite.

Answer (score 0):

It uses WPA2-PSK AES.
You can not change encryption method.

to so see what changes you can make, such as change the key or network name (SSID) you can use:

```
netsh wlan show
```

to list the options.

for example to change the key:

```
netsh wlan set key = "my passord" keyusage=persistent
```